# How to get all folders on given path in Linux?

Tags: perl, glob

Directory structure

```
Attachments/TADDE12345
Attachments/TADDE12346
Attachments/TADDE12347
Attachments/TADDE12348
Attachments/TADDE12349
Attachments/TADDE12350
```

I have to get all folders name inside attachments directory without using any cpan modules?

Comment: `glob()` and `File::Find` might prove useful.

Answer (score 5):

See [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

> In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
>   expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such
>   filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

If you need directories only from the given path:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                               
use strict;
use warnings;              

my $dirpath = "/Attachments";

opendir(DIR, $dirpath);

while (my $entry = readdir DIR) {
    next if ($entry eq "." or $entry eq "..");
    $entry = $dirpath . $entry;
    print "$entry\n" if (-d $entry);
}

closedir DIR;
```